# Submit a form directly to request url

Tags: node.js, http-post, puppeteer

In puppeteer I directly submit forms by filling out the data needed then clicking the submit button.  I'm wondering how could I submit a form directly to an api like the web page does.
In example on this page when I submit the form it does a network request post to

```
https://www.example.com/api/v3/user?timestamp=1592947755672
```

Request Method: POST
Then the Request Payload is a json object.

```
{firstName: "John",
lastName: "Travis"}
```

How can I pass my object to the url so that I could by pass filling out the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something to do outside of puppeteer, but you can solve it with Node.

I.) If you prefer to solve it without a new dependency but with longer lines of callbacks you can do it with Node's "http" module [`http.request(options\[, callback\])`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

II.) If you don't mind having a new dependency in your project then the npm package **[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)** was used for a long time as a simplified HTP client. It is deprecated as of February 11th 2020 so I'd suggest to use **[node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)** (0 dependencies) or **[axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)** (1 dependency).

*Request* collects alternative libraries in [this](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) GitHub issue.